# Datetimepicker not working in Rails - Boootsrap4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looking to build a date-time input field in rails with bootstrap4. The toggle shows up but does not expand, showing only the clock icon.

I wrote the following:

```
<div class='input-group date'>
         <span class="input-group-addon">
              <span class="fas fa-clock  fa-2x" style="color:#44B5EB"></span>
          </span><%= f.text_field (:start), :class => "form-control", id: 'datetimepickerA' %>

      </div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepickerA').datetimepicker({
            defaultDate: "<%= DateTime.now %>",
            format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
        });
    });
</script>
```

And when I click on the clock, it expands, briefly shows the calendar then shutdown to leave the image that you can see.

[image]

Does anyone knows what could cause this ?

What i noticed:

When date format is specified -> calendar shows and work (with no time of course)

When date and time format are specified -> Calendar shows as per the picture.

When no format is specified  -> Calendar shows as per the picture.

The following code works perfectly, but it is fully `HTML`. I am now looking to convert it to add `:start` attribute:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker8" data-target-input="nearest">
              <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker8"/>
              <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker8" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: If that works fine without the defaultDate, the option probably doesn't expect this format. There's a doc for your datetime picker?  Maybe you should return a string correctly formatted with `.strftime`

Comment: that would be strange because when i do not specify any format I have the same error.